# Timer counter 0 and make a real second problem

Tags: c, timer, avr, atmelstudio

I want to simulate a code in portuse. 
I have a led connected to a pin of micro with 2MHZ frequency. 
I wannat code in timer0 with presclare 64. 
I calculate that it need to 31128 count in timer. 
But timer0 can calculate only until 255. 
So i deside to use overflow interupt and define a variabke to count oveflows. 
If overdlow reach 122.07 one second pass. 
I use 122 overflow interupt. But for 0.07 remain i need to count until 18 in tcnt. So i deside to use OCR fir tha.

My question is this: is this method true or false? 
Abd how should i write this code?

Comment: Is you problem, that you do not get an EXACT second?

Answer (score 0):

The question is: do you want your counter in the long term to count time intervals? 
Or you want some event to happen exactly each second? With what tolerance?

For example, if you want to count, let's say, 10 minutes, showing seconds counter on a display, then 10-20 ms jitter is accepted, i.e. if your second counter on the display will be updated 10 ms earlier or later, it doesn't matter. In this case you can use Bresenham's algorithm to correct errors. You increase some variable by amount of a timer overflow interval (256). When the variable exceeds one second value (which is 2000000 / 64 = 31250) you decrease it by it's value and process the per-second event. In long terms the second counter will exactly count seconds. Obviously, you can divide both numbers by the same amount. I.e. use 128 and 15625, respectively.

```
uint16_t second_counter = 0;
uint16_t counter_error = 0;

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
  counter_error += 128; // Increase the error counter;
  if (counter_error >= 15625) { // On overflow
    counter_error -= 15625; // Decrease the error counter;

    second_counter++; // Increase the second counter, or do any other once-per-second action
  }
}
```

The each-second event inside the condition will fire not exactly on second boundaries, after 122 or 123 timer overflows. But in average it will be exactly once per second. This method is good when the timer is used at the same time for something else, and changing of it's resolution is not possible.

But if you want to have the second event EXACTLY each second, then use the counter in CTC mode, limiting it's top value in the way it will have integer number of overflows per second.

Let's say, you can choose 64 prescaler, and set TOP value to 249 (thus making the timer period equals to 250), which gives you exactly 125 overflows per second.

```
uint8_t overflow_counter = 0;
uint16_t second_counter = 0;
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) {
  overflow_counter++;
  if (overflow_counter >= 125) { // waiting for 125th overflow;
    overflow_counter = 0;  // reset the counter;

    second_counter++; // Increase the second counter, or do any other once-per-second action
  }
}

OCR0A = 249; // from 0 to 249 = 250 counts.
TIMSK0 = (1 << TOIE0); // Allow overflow interrupt
TCCR0A = (1 << WGM01); // Enable CTC mode. OCRA defines the top value
TCCR0B = (1 << CS01) | (1 << CS00); // Start with 1:64 prescaler
sei(); // Enable interrupts
```